# ASP.NET wiki with AD authentication

Tags: asp.net, active-directory, wiki-engine

I am exploring the options of establishing a wiki site for my company's division of developers, numbering over a hundred. We are a pure Microsoft (Certified Partner) shop, so it is natural to base an implementation on ASP.NET and IIS for familiarity's sake as well as extended learning opportunities.

It looks like Screwturn wiki does not offer a user provider that can hook up to Active Directory. Is there a wiki engine that natively supports AD? Managing two user bases would not be the most efficient of activities when we wish to control access.

Comment: With 100 developers, I'd think you'd be able to write an AD provider for ScrewTurn in a day.

Comment: Managed to discover AD providers written by european developers. Now to find out which is better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

UPDATE: looks like ScrewTurn now has an official AD provider

http://www.screwturn.eu/blog/?p=255

Answer (score 3):

Have you had a look at Sharepoint Wiki? Sicne you are a Microsoft shop, it's probably the easiest to set up.

As expected, it integrates with Active Directory out of the box. It's not really written about much since it's part of Sharepoint Server. [Here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2007.01.wiki.aspx)'s the Microsoft Page

To be honest, it's not the greatest Wiki around. The markup is HTML based, which is clunky coming from MediaWiki, but It fit in nicely.

Answer (score 2):

The *[N2](http://n2cms.com/) Open Source ASP.NET CMS* is a lightweight CMS framework to help you build great web sites that anyone can update. It contains a package of functional templates with News, Wiki, Photo Galleries, FAQs, RSS, Data Entry, Polls and more. Also, N2 leverages on ASP.NET features such as existing web controls site map and membership providers.

Answer (score 1):

We've been using [Perspective Wiki](http://www.high-beyond.com/perspective.aspx?action=view&page=perspective:Welcome) - it integrates with Windows AD fairly well, and has most of the features you'd expect of a wiki - which is more than could be said for the SP Wiki - we've not migrated to MOSS wiki's yet mostly because of missing features.

Answer (score 1):

[MindTouch](http://www.mindtouch.com) is OpenSource and .Net based.  Ohloh has rated it as a 5.  The source code is pretty tight, and there are connectors for SqlServer as well as a scripting language.  Finally it supports LDAP and ActiveDirectory.

MindTouch is a generally considered a good open source alternative to SharePoint as you can quickly create customizations with it's toolkits as well as integrate with MS Office.

Answer (score 0):

According to their website [LiteWiki](http://www.andrewfaust.com/) supports the ASP.NET membership providers and is pretty lightweight.

Answer (score 0):

It might not be what you are looking for but my compnay has MediaWiki on Linux/Apache running with integrated AD security. It is locked down to users in a particular AD group and we log on with our AD credentials.

MediaWiki seems to be a very good wiki too.

Comment: Our local administrator would not have the expertise to manage a Linux/Apache server.

Answer (score 0):

You can add AD support with a couple line of code. Check the Screwturn wiki forums for various examples